# Optimizing Django: nested queries vs relation lookups

Tags: python, django, optimization

I have a legacy code which uses nested ORM query, which produces SQL SELECT query with JOIN, and conditions which also contains SELECT and JOIN. Execution of this query takes enormous time. By the way, when I execute this query in raw SQL, taken from `Django_ORM_query.query`, it performs with reasonable time.

What are best practices for optimization in such cases? 
Would the query perform faster if I will use `ManyToMany` and `ForeignKey` relations?

Comment: If you are saying that the same SQL code runs OK when run manually, you don't need to optimize that code.

Comment: Problem is in that query servres for fetching items from catalog with specified parameters, and also it uses models of CMS, which has some own not so easy to understand specific features.

Answer (score 9):

Performance issue in Django is usually caused by following relations in a loop, which causes multiple database queries. If you have [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) installed, you can check for how many queries you're doing and figure out which query needs to be optimized. The debug toolbar also shows you the time of each queries, which is essential for optimizing django, you're missing out a lot if you didn't have it installed or didn't use it.

You'd generally solve the problem of following relations by using [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

A page generally should have at **most** 20-30 queries, any more and it's going to seriously affect performance. Most pages should only have 5-10 queries. You want to reduce the number of queries because round trip is the number one killer of database performance. In general one big query is faster than 100 small queries.

The number two killer of database performance is much rarer a problem, though it sometimes arises because of techniques that reduces the number of queries. Your query might simply be too big, if this is the case, you should use defer() or only() so you don't load large fields that you know you won't be using.

Comment: Main page, on site which I need to optimize, loads with 400+ queries :)

Comment: Yeah … that's WAY way too many queries. Way too many. We'd have to see your models, templates and views to tell you a better way to do it.

Comment: @user2115719: I agree it's too much queries, try to see if you can preload related objects with select_related or prefetch_related.

Comment: They are not mine, its legacy code! :) I actually found how they generated. Even before I profile site - that was not hard to guess - there one 'hot' loop where all mess happens. And actually I wrote wrong question - this is not heavy query cause long page load, but that loop. Im misguided my self when profiling "manually", placing flags in code - I just misplaced flag and it measured time of whole loop, not just query evaluation. Sorry Django! :)

Comment: By the way - site running on Django 1.3 - it doesnt have `prefetch_related()` - is it possible somehow to manually manufacture prefetching? For example if I write - `items.objects.values('related__value')` - would it similar to `prefetch_related()`?

Comment: @user2115719: yes you can, what prefetch_related does is to create a second query that queries related_value, then assigns them as attribute the result of the first query. This uses two queries instead of n+1. See http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/ for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, use [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) SQL. That's a completely valid optimization in Django world.

Comment: I was afraid to say this because I thought it was my dirty little secret.

Comment: The [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method has had my back covered in most situations, the ORM in general seems to cover over 90% of use cases. If it's just too much hassle though, raw SQL is the way. Everything in moderation, I've seen horrible code where people didn't seem to be aware that the ORM even existed.

Comment: So far, I've yet to need to use `raw()` or `extra()`; when I had performance problem, judicious use of `select_related()`, `prefetch_related()` (or in older Django, an equivalent to `prefetch_related`) had always brought things back to one-second barrier for me (one-second is my limit for acceptable page generation time). Be aware that using `raw()` query  might limit your database independence.

Comment: Eh. Database independence is generally a joke anyway.

Comment: @JackShedd: not to me, I generally develop with sqlite and deploy to MySQL. I've even once deployed a medium sized django app originally designed for sqlite and MySQL to Postgre without changing any application code, and the app was never previously tested on Postgre.

Comment: Why is it weird? That database independence is possible? What is usually standing between you and database independence?

Comment: No, that anyone would care about it. Database independence is a side effect of the ORM abstraction, not its goal. It makes absolutely no sense to make it a goal. Each RDMS (or even SQLite) has it's own performance/feature particulars, which can be wielded to produce huge performance gains, simplify models, more integrity, etc. To care about database independence is to say, "I only want to use a subset of my databases power". The ORM is there to make simple things simpler, not make complex things impossible.